# Constructing a linear transform with kernel equal to image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I got a question in an exam saying for R^4->r^4 I have to construct a linear transform for which kernel and image are equal.

How can I do this.I had no idea of solving this problem and they also asked if the linear transform obtained is same for R^5->R^5 or not.

Please give me an idea of this..

Comment: Do you know the *rank-nullity formula*?

Comment: Yeah rank+nullity=n

Comment: Good: what does that tell you about the kernel of a possible example in $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: I don't know :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear map $A$ from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ with kernel equal to its image is:
$$
A: (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \mapsto (x_3, x_4, 0, 0).
$$
As pointed out in the comments, you can use the theorem rank + nullity = $n$ to show that there is no such a map for $n = 5$.

Comment: How did you get this answer ?A:(x1,x2,x3,x4)↦(x3,x4,0,0).
A:(x1,x2,x3,x4)↦(x3,x4,0,0).

Comment: Since we want the kernel to be equal to the image, in particular their dimensions must be the same. Moreover, from the theorem rank + kernel = 4, we have that their dimension must be 2. 
The subspace $V = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) : x_3 = x_4 = 0\}$ is has dimension 2. Then I just created a map map $A$ such that ker$A = V = $ im$(A)$.

Comment: ok thanks bro...